# How to update a cylinder height in open3D

Tags: python, open3d

I want to change the height of a cylinder in open3D. Is it possible? If yes, how can I proceed?
I'm using `open3d-python==0.7.0.0`.

```
import open3d as o3d
cylinder = o3d.geometry.create_mesh_cylinder()
# ...
# doing something and then update here:
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct solution, the idea is to use scaling. However the provided scaling function `open3d.geometry.Geometry3D.scale`, scale the object along the 3 axis. Fortunately, we can update vertices as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66609681/9794186):

```
cylinder.vertices = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(
np.asarray(mesh.vertices) * np.array([1., 1., 2.]) )
```