# Scaling along a single axis in open3d

Tags: python, scale, open3d

Is there a function to scale a mesh along `y-axis` only (left) after its creation?

I tried the `open3d.geometry.Geometry3D.scale` function, but it scales along the `3-axis` (right).

```
import open3d as o3d
cylinder = o3d.geometry.create_mesh_cylinder(radius=1, height=3)
cylinder_scaled.scale(2) # I got the cylinder on the left.
```

[image: open3d scaling]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert mesh vertices to numpy array first. Convert back after scaling.

```py
cylinder.vertices = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(
    np.asarray(cylinder.vertices) * np.array([1., 1., 2.]) )
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! Just edit your solution replace mesh by cylinder! thanks again.